# Strapi Default Admin User Login via post request or api url

Tags: node.js, authentication, session, strapi, koa

Currently i'm using strapi v 4.10.2 community version and trying to login as default admin user in browser through post request / api url trigger, of course the input is identifier and password, so rather than typing at login form i just prepare fixed input and trigger login procedure through post request/ api link. So far i have tried this by making custom plugin and have tried auth/local method in strapi doc which return jwt token to make authenticated api request, but it doesn't make user automatically logged in browser. Any help for this problem or how to use the code from strapi built-in code or any other idea?

I have tried to use code snippet from index.js from auth page files because i though in order to be logged in browser you need to set token and user info data. This is example of how i use that code snippet in simple api file inside strapi:

```
'use strict';

const { getService } = require('@strapi/admin/server/utils');
const { auth } = require('@strapi/helper-plugin');
/* A set of functions called "actions" for `login` */

module.exports = {async login(ctx) {
const { email, password } = ctx.request.body;

// Find user by email and password
const user = await strapi.query('admin::user').findOne({ email, password });

if (!user) {
  ctx.throw(401, 'Invalid credentials');
}

// Generate JWT token
const jwtToken = getService('token').createJwtToken(user);
const sanitizedUser = getService('user').sanitizeUser(user);
// Store the JWT token and user info in the session storage
ctx.session.jwtToken = jwtToken;
ctx.session.userInfo = sanitizedUser;

// Send success response
ctx.body = {
  message: 'Login successful',
};
```

},
};

What i want to use the code is this, but i don't know how because it return element undefined error

```
auth.setToken(jwtToken , false);
auth.setUserInfo(sanitizedUser , false);
```